# is a pointer to data member its offset?

Tags: c++, member-pointers, offsetof

Am I safe to assume that the offset of a data member (`offsetof(mystruct, myfield)`) is numerically equal to the raw value of a member pointer retrieved with `&mystruct::myfield`, or is it implementation dependent?

Comment: No is should not be assumed so. You forget about the overhead(memory) the compiler may insert for managing the memory so allocated for the object.

Comment: A better question would be: since you know the two forms, why would you *not* use the pointer to member ? :)

Comment: I'm actually considering to use pointer to members, as my program does some low level tricks with offsetof, and I want to "elevate" them to a more standard form.

Comment: From page 7 here: http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

"Borland compilers add an offset of 1 to data member pointers in order to distinguish a
pointer to the first data member from a NULL pointer, represented by 0. The other compilers
have no offset, but represent a NULL data member pointer by the value -1."

So there's a very specific example of when you can't rely on it, in case you were wondering if this was simply academic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; the implementation of a pointer-to-member is not specified, and there is no defined conversion to get the "raw" value.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, it is implementation-dependent, of course. In real life, yes, the most popular implementation of pointer-to-data-member pointers is (or is based on) plan-and-simple offset, i.e. the same thing that `offsetof` evaluates to.

Some implementations use the exact offset, resorting to `0xFFF...` pattern to represent the null-pointer value. Some implementatiuons reserve `0x000...` pattern for null-pointer value, while incrementing all "non-null" offsets by `1`.